# Checking for preselected option value when page loads

Tags: jquery, smarty, onload

I am dynamically setting an option set to a certain value when the page loads. How would I check for that value on the load of the page and then change another divs contents? My best guess is below, but I've had no luck.

```
$("select[name=mySelections]").onload.function() {
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == 'myvalue') {
            $("#myDiv").html("Test");
        }
}
```

My Selector

```
{html_options name="mySelections" options=$myOptions selected=$test->One}
```

My html

```
<div id="myDiv"
{foreach from $whatever to $this}
<input type="checkbox" name="{$this->Name}" value="{$this->value}" />
{/foreach
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to check if the HTML select element is loaded, but you should check if the DOM is loaded instead, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("select[name=mySelections] option:selected").val() == 'myvalue') {
        $("#myDiv").html("Test");
    }
});
```